# Issue with returning distinct records based on single column (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have the table "members" (shown below), how would I go about getting the record of the first occurrence of a membership_id (Oracle).

**Expected results**

```
123                 John                      Doe                      A       P
313                 Michael                   Casey                    A       A
113                 Luke                      Skywalker                A       P
```

**Table - members**

```
membership_id       first_name                last_name                status  type
123                 John                      Doe                      A       P
313                 Michael                   Casey                    A       A
113                 Luke                      Skywalker                A       P
123                 Bob                       Dole                     A       A
313                 Lucas                     Smith                    A       A
```

Comment: Since rows in a table are inherently unordered, what is the logic for determining "first"?  What column or columns can we `ORDER BY` in order to determine the "first" row?  In your example, it looks like we can order by `last_name` but I'm not sure if that is true generally.

Comment: Order is determined based on membership_id and 'type' (desc).  My example is obviously in this order, but that does not take away from the issue I am having. The data in my program is not actually a table but the results of an already existing query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT membership_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       status,
       type
  FROM( SELECT membership_id,
               first_name,
               last_name,
               status,
               type,
               rank() over (partition by membership_id
                                order by type desc) rnk
          FROM members )
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

will work for your sample data set.  If you can have ties-- that is, multiple rows with the same `membership_id` and the same maximum `type`-- this query will return all those rows.  If you only want to return one of the rows where there is a tie, you would either need to add additional criteria to the `order by` to ensure that all ties are broken or you would need to use the `row_number` function rather than `rank` which will arbitrarily break ties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.*
FROM Members AS A inner join
     (Select membership_id, first(first_name) AS FN, first(last_name) AS LN 
      From Members
      Group by membership_id) AS B
     ON A.membership_id=B.membership_id and A.first_name=B.FN and A.last_name=B.LN
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `first`? This isn't an Oracle function as far as I'm aware. Do you mean `max` or `min`, which will select an arbitrary combination (probably not what the OP wants?

Comment: Yep. Your right, I have no experience in Oracle so I was just trying to point in a possible path. In regards to the max/min the question said "getting the record of the first occurrence of a membership_id (Oracle)" so I assumed getting the first occurrence was the goal but I might have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from members 
where rowid in (
    select min(rowid)
    from members
    group by membership_id
)
```